# Are there any ways to recover hearts besides finding hearts in the field?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm in the middle of the desert, clinging onto live with only half a heart, desperate for anything that can recover my life, and naturally, I don't have any bottles with me.

In what ways can I recover my hearts, or am I required to scavenge the desert for any hearts?

Comment: Would it be more efficient to die? :P

Comment: @MatthewRead: If you don't have fairies with you, I'd say so!  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a bottle, the only other way to gain hearts is to find a chair to sit in.  If you sit there long enough, you can recover all your missing hearts.

Comment: Sleeping is also an option but you won't find any beds in the desert.

Comment: I didn't know that sleeping/resting gives you health. That's great!

Comment: and I didn't know sitting in a chair restores your health, Great!

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember when you get the ability, but you can also douse for hearts after a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

In many locations you can find heart flowers or distant pots/ grass you can use your BEETLE for if you can't go over there yourself (yet).  Your Beetle can cut grass and break jars and then you can pick up the hearts and it brings them back to you.